# Processing ^ symbol for get powers of polynomials using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to process a string to detect polynomials and get their powers and coefficients, but my regex seems to have a problem and always gives me wrong results or in some cases, causes an exception.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]?(?:(?:\\d+x\\^\\d+)|(?:\\d+x)|(?:\\d+)|(?:x)))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expr);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if(matcher.group(1).matches("[0-9]+")) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        b = 0;
    } else if(matcher.group(1).matches("\\^")) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, expr.indexOf("x")));
        b = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, expr.indexOf("^"))+1);
    } else {
        a = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, expr.indexOf("x")));
        b = 1;
    }
}
```

This should be able to detect and give me valid outputs if something like

> 5x^3 +2x +1

is given as an input. (This is part of a bigger method so input is broken into pieces before being processed by these lines of code)
Since I am new to programming, I cannot seem to understand whether the problem is with regex or java syntax.

Comment: I can tell you so much: you java syntax is ok and the regular expression is at least [not invalid](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output), still it may not do what you want. Since you didn't mention which Exceptions were thrown, or a call stack for that matter, I will assume that they were NumberFormatExceptions and you feed invalid input to parseInt

Comment: you are using `matcher.group(1)` and probably this is causing exceptions in some cases when group = 1 doesn't exist

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output, and show exactly how your current code doesn't work.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a good solution for this problem. You would be better off with a conventional scanner and parser.

Answer (score 1):

I guess an expression similar to,

```
\^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(x)
```

#### [Demo (for decimals)](https://regex101.com/r/0g7oBj/1/)

or,

```
\^(-?\d+)|(-?\d+)|(x)
```

#### [Demo (for integers)](https://regex101.com/r/Juwziy/1/)

might be good to look into so that you'd solve the problem.

---

> Here, the first group finds the exponent values, the second group
>   returns the coefficients and the third group returns the `x` (so that
>   you can figure out if there is a constant in the equation).

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\^(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|(x)";
        final String string = "5x^3 +2x +1\n"
             + "5x^-3.1 +2x -1\n"
             + "5x^3.23 -2012.12x +10.12\n"
             + "-5x^3.54 +2x -1.512";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: 5
Group 1: null
Group 2: 5
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^3
Group 1: 3
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Group 2: 2
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: 1
Group 1: null
Group 2: 1
Group 3: null
Full match: 5
Group 1: null
Group 2: 5
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^-3.1
Group 1: -3.1
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Group 2: 2
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Group 2: -1
Group 3: null
Full match: 5
Group 1: null
Group 2: 5
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^3.23
Group 1: 3.23
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: -2012.12
Group 1: null
Group 2: -2012.12
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: 10.12
Group 1: null
Group 2: 10.12
Group 3: null
Full match: -5
Group 1: null
Group 2: -5
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^3.54
Group 1: 3.54
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Group 2: 2
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: -1.512
Group 1: null
Group 2: -1.512
Group 3: null
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0g7oBj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/0g7oBj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Example 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\^(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|(x)";
        final String string = "12x^11 +10x^9 -8x^7 +9x^6 -5x^3 +2x -1";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: 12
Group 1: null
Group 2: 12
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^11
Group 1: 11
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 10
Group 1: null
Group 2: 10
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^9
Group 1: 9
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: -8
Group 1: null
Group 2: -8
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^7
Group 1: 7
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 9
Group 1: null
Group 2: 9
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^6
Group 1: 6
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: -5
Group 1: null
Group 2: -5
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: ^3
Group 1: 3
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
Full match: 2
Group 1: null
Group 2: 2
Group 3: null
Full match: x
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: x
Full match: -1
Group 1: null
Group 2: -1
Group 3: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution which produces an array of coefficients for each exponent value (0 being the constant). It searches for either a constant value or something of the form *a*x^*y* where the ^*y* part is optional. The `a` variable should be sized according to the maximum exponent you expect in the equation.

```
int[] a = new int[4];
int exp, coeff;
String expr = "-5x^3 + 2x - 1";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:((?:^|\\s*[+-]\\s*)\\d*)x(?:\\^(\\d+))?)|(?:[+-]\\s*\\d+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expr);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if(matcher.group(1).matches("[+-]\\s*\\d+")) {
        // the constant part
        a[0] = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1).replace(" ", ""));
    }
    else {
        // a variable part
        coeff = (matcher.group(2) != "") ? Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2).replace(" ", "")) : 1;
        exp = (matcher.group(3) != "" && matcher.group(3) != null) ? Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)) : 1;
        a[exp] = coeff;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Output (for this example)

```
[-1, 2, 0, -5]
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/FBOIKM87066)